# google or-tools glop: how to create array of pointer to const object?

Tags: c++, pointers, or-tools

i am trying to use google glop for a research project [official site](https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/cpp#simple_example)

I am playing with the example coming with the source code

```
MPVariable* const x = solver.MakeNumVar(0.0, 1, "x");
```

I can see how to create variables in glop.

however, I don't understand, what if the number of variables are not given at compile time? if the program receives command from network and construct the problem on-the-fly.

I suppose there should be an array of variables?

```
std::vector<MPVariable*> variables;// is this correct? or it should be:
std::vector<MPVariable const *> variables; // never saw syntax like this before

variables.resize(100);//say, 100 variables
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < variables.size(); ++i){
    variables[i] = solver.MakeNumVar(0.0, createSomeNumber(), createName());
}
```

is this how it supposed to work? can anyone share some experience here?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want pointers to const variables, I would go with:

```
std::vector<const MPVariable*> variables;
```

But I have always used

```
std::vector<MPVariable*> variables;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please mind that you didn't place the `const` consistantly:

> ```
> `MPVariable* const x`
> ```

vs.

> ```
> `std::vector<MPVariable const *>`
> ```

The function `MakeNumVar()` returns a `MPCariable*` so nothing has to be `const`.